# C# Performance of LINQ vs. foreach iterator block

Tags: linq, select, iterator, foreach

1) Do these generate the same byte code?

2) If not, is there any gain in using one over the other in certain circumstances?

```
// LINQ select statement
return from item in collection
    select item.Property;

// foreach in an iterator block
foreach (item in collection)
    yield return item.Property;
```

Comment: hint: use IL Disassembler to see byte code yourself.

Comment: hint 2: run the code and time it to test the performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. They don't generate the same code but boil down to the same thing, you get an object implementing `IEnumerable<typeof(Property)>`. The difference is that linq provides iterator from its library (in this case most likely by using `WhereSelectArrayIterator` or `WhereSelectListIterator`) whereas in the second example you yourself generate an iterator block that dissects a collection. An iterator block method is always, by ways of compiler magic, compiled as a separate class implementing `IEnumerable<typeof(yield)>` which you don't see but instantiate implicitly when you call iterator block method.
2. Performance wise, #1 should be slightly (but just slightly) faster for indexable collections because when you loop through the resulting `IEnumerable` you go directly from your foreach into collection retrieval in an optimized linq iterator. In example #2 you go from foreach into your iterator block's foreach and from there into collection retrieval and your performance depends mostly on how smart the compiler is at optimizing yield logic. In any case I would imagine that for any complex collection mechanism the cost of retrieval marginalizes this difference.

IMHO, I would always go with #1, if nothing else it saves me from having to write a separate method just for iterating.

Comment: Good point about performance being slightly faster for the framework iterators. But I checked them out and WhereSelectListIterator has the same implementation as WhereSelectEnumerableIterator so I'd say they're the same speed. WhereSelectArrayIterator uses the index properly.

Comment: Well, I stated its faster for indexed sources. But yeah, I saw the `WhereSelectListIterator` issue too, which is kind of weird if you ask me. `List<T>` is specifically geared towards O(1) indexed retrieval, same as Arrays. Makes absolutely no sense to walk the `List<T>` through `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. No they don't generate the same byte code. The first one returns a pre-existing class in the framework. The second one returns a compiler generated state machine that returns the items from the collection. That state machine is very similar to the class that exists in the framework already.
2. I doubt there's much performance difference between the two. Both are doing very similar things in the end.

Comment: I agree with Cameron. The first statement does a `yield return` as well, but the difference is that the C# compiler team wrote that `yield return` in the `Enumerable.Select` extension method. In fact, the `select` will be faster, because you reuse existing code which makes your assembly smaller and less code will consume less memory which will cause less cache misses, thus equals better performance (but this is very hard to test using a test setup).

Comment: @Steven I'd be very surprised if the amount of extra memory consumed by the extra code would cause any measurable difference in performance.

Comment: @Cameron: C# generates an extra class when you write a `yield`. It's not much, but do this a thousand times and the difference can become measurable.

Comment: @Steven: The class is generated by the compiler, at compile time. At run time both methods instantiate a class and return it. The only difference is the first one returns an instance of the class from the framework, while the second one returns an instance of the class generated at compile time.

Comment: @Cameron: Every time you write a method with a `yield return` the C# compiler generates a new class. This generated class ends up as IL. During runtime this IL gets JITted. JITted code takes up memory.

Comment: @Steven: Yes JITed code takes up memory. But if you call it thousands of times it's still only JITed once, and then reused.

Comment: @Cameron: True, but that's not the point. Code takes up memory and this can impact performance. Because of this Microsoft decided to change the JIT of .NET 3.5 SP1 to do *less* inlining of methods than before. They found out that, while inlining locally improves performance, it generates more code and their benchmarks signaled less overall performance. See here for more information about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx.