# Are there some disadvantages in using "a lot" of LINQ to Objects statements?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I come from Java programming and switching to C# programming I discovered the extreme powerful of LINQ.

In my recent implementation I noticed that I use it (expecially LINQ to Objects) very often in my code to avoid `foreach` loops, to search elements in lists and for similar tasks.

Now I'm wondering if there is some performance disadvantage in massively use Linq to Objects...

Comment: *to avoid foreach loops, to search elements in lists* You probably mean LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entites, don't you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322586/c-sharp-performance-of-linq-vs-foreach-iterator-block <--Somebody who asked a similar question

Comment: @Mr.Steak sorry, you're right! I edited my question.

Comment: "Massively use LINQ"? Ok stop right there. Don't use *anything* "massively". LINQ is a nice hammer, but many problems aren't nails.

Comment: @davioooh The answer is: Even if it's slower, the difference is probably either not measurable or negligible small. Readability and maintainability trump (in most cases).

Comment: This is an usual question, you might find a lot of information about it just on google. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044400/linq-performance-faq) might help you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Linq is slower than native C# loops.
C# is slower than C++.
C++ is slower than assembly.
Assembly is slower than designing your own custom microprocessor.

So you should always design your own custom microprocessor instead of using Linq.....

Is there a performance hit?  Probably, but you won't know how much until you actually *measure it*.  It may be small enough that it won't be significant and you can spend the time you would have spent avoiding Linq tackling the parts of the application that *do* benefit by optimization.

Bottom line is - build your app using the libraries and frameworks that make you the most productive, then optimize from there.  You may find out that the slowest part of your app isn't the Linq code at all, so you'd be optimizing the wrong thing if you forbade it just because it *might* be slower than rolling your own loops.

Comment: How is Linq slower than C# when it is C# (extension methods)?

Comment: Overhead of creating iterators, improper usage (multiple scans), generic vs. tuned code, etc.

Comment: You have to be fully aware that LINQ has deferred execution, it executes only when it reaches a foreach, if you combine this with lazy-loading capabilities of some frameworks such as Entity Framework, you could end up with huge waiting times. LINQ is a great tool, if you master it, you won't notice significant slowdowns. You can also parallelize LINQ for cpu bound queries... just remember, a great power comes with a great responsibility

Answer (score 11):

To answer your question objectively, LINQ makes heavy use of delegates and iterators, which has the overhead of instantiations (delegates and iterators) and method calls (delegate invocation and `MoveNext()` on iterators). Now, a `foreach` (on a `List<T>`) will have the overhead of the iterator, but not the overhead of delegates. So it's expected that LINQ will be slower here than a `foreach`.

Likewise, iterating through the list using the `[i]` indexer is expected to be faster still because it also doesn't have the overhead of the iterator. Even faster is not using a `List<T>` but an array. But even that has the overhead of array bounds checks (the bit that throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you try to go outside array bounds) and *that* can be avoided by using raw memory access through pointers, or by simply iterating the entire list (`for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) { Console.WriteLine(array[i]); }` won't have bounds checks because the compiler can prove this loop will never go out of bounds).

Those are the varying degrees of overhead that the various ways of iteration bring with them. Do those overheads matter? If you're doing 10,000 x 10,000 matrix multiplication, then yes. Otherwise, probably not unless you've measured it to be (which is a tired old answer, but no less valid).

However, aside from those facts it also matters *how* you use them. Say you want a list of customers who were born after 1980 from a larger pile of customers and do further processing on them. Without LINQ, you be would pretty much forced to `foreach` the original customer list and create an intermediate list that you put the customers who were born after 1980 into. *With* LINQ, you won't need the intermediate list which saves quite a lot of overhead (creating the list, calling `Add` on it, resizing it several times most likely as it grows) and is likely to be faster. And it's certainly more memory efficient, as the customers born after 1980 are 'streamed' in one by one without the intermediate list taking up memory. With LINQ, you can potentially process an infinitely long sequence.

Another performance reason to use LINQ is that parallelization of certain operations becomes trivial with the `AsParallel()` call at the end of a query.

So to answer your question if there's a performance disadvantage to using LINQ:

*It depends.*

Answer (score 0):

With any abstraction where you loose control and have to depend on implementations where you are not aware of the underlying code there is a tendency to have slower performance (because LINQ has to be generic and cannot be fully optimized for one type of object at the expense of another).  However how much depends on your situation.  For example if your application is hit millions of times per day and you need absolute performance then using LINQ to entities for database queries is probably not a great idea, you may want to do performance optimizations on your SQL queries that LINQ will not allow you to do.  But if your application is used as part of an enterprise application where the number of users is relatively small then you're probably ok with using LINQ heavily.  So my answer is yes it's going to be slower, but it may not matter because of your situation.

Comment: Doesn't StackOverflow itself run on linq to sql? I wouldn't count out the performance there.

Comment: You're right, they do use linq to SQL but they also use some straight SQL in places see Jeff Attwoods answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/is-stackoverflow-still-using-linq-to-sql-as-the-orm.  So it depends....

Comment: Stackoverflow has switched to pure SQL in combination with Dapper for queries, but still uses LINQ-to-SQL for updating/inserting as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking LINQ offers no performance benefits, but some implementations of it might. If you want performant code then you still need to have a broad awareness of the algorithmic time complexity of each LINQ query.

E.g. a common scenario I've seen is to perform a WHERE clause over a list for a specific value, which will cause a scan of the items in the list, which will have O(n) complexity. Such an operation can of course be achieved with O(1) complexity if you maintain a hash table (e.g. `Dictionary<K,V>`) to perform the lookups against.