# Linq: Return a new list of different type

Tags: c#, linq

Given a return of type "AccountItem", I want to filter and sort to a new list of type `FDKeyValue<>`

I am trying to do this without looping and I thought I could do something like this:

```
var monthlyList = accountList.Where(x => x.RoleType == "Metric")
     .OrderBy(x => x.EntityName)
     .Select(new FDKeyValue<long, string>{}
     {
         "Field", "Field"
     }
);
```

here is what I have working with a loop

```
var accountList = DBEntity.ReturnAccountListBySearch((int)this.PageLanguageType, "");
var monthlyList = accountList.Where(x => x.RoleType == "Metric").OrderBy(x => x.EntityName).ToList();
this.MonthlyAccountList = new FDKeyValue<long,string>();
foreach (var item in monthlyList)
{
    this.MonthlyAccountList.Add(item.EntityID, item.EntityName);
}
```

Comment: so the FDKeyValue<> is a collection itself and it has an Add method, correct?

Comment: Performance consideration of `select` vs `foreach` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322586/c-sharp-performance-of-linq-vs-foreach-iterator-block

Comment: Yep the FDKeyValue is a Generic tuple that inherits LIST.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax must help

```
    var monthlyList = accountList.Where(x => x.RoleType == "Metric")
            .OrderBy(x => x.EntityName)
            .Select(x => new FDKeyValue<long, string>
                {
                 x.EntityID, x.EntityName
              }
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.